# Laravel whereHas on multiple relationships

Tags: laravel-4

Does anyone know if this [new feature](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations) can be performed on multiple relationships?

For example, I have a query where I want to filter on not only the club name ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116742/wherehas-orwherehas-not-constraining-the-query-as-expected)) but also the territory name.

In this example, I'd like query results where the club (club relationship) name is Arsenal and the the region is Australia (territory relationship)

```
$ret->with('territory')->with('homeClub')->with('awayClub');
    $ret->whereHas('territory',function( $query ){
            $query->where('region','Australia');
        })->whereHas('homeClub', function ( $query ) {
            $query->where('name', 'Arsenal' );
        })->orWhereHas('awayClub', function ( $query ) {
            $query->where('name', 'Arsenal' );
        });
```

When executing this query - the result isn't constraining the territory `whereHas` just the clubs one.

Can whereHas be chained to filter the results on previous relationship's whereHas? Any suggestions if not?

thanks

jon

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes that's possible.

The generated SQL will probably be:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE (territory constraint) AND (homeClub constratint) OR (awayClub constraint)
```

This means that if `awayClub constraint` is satisfied, the line will be retrieved. I think you want to add a parenthesis to the generated sql:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE (territory constraint) AND ((homeClub constratint) OR (awayClub constraint))
```

to do that, you need to nest both queries inside a where:

```
$ret->with('territory')->with('homeClub')->with('awayClub');
    $ret->whereHas('territory',function( $query ){
        $query->where('region','Australia');
    })
    ->where(function($subQuery)
    {   
        $subQuery->whereHas('homeClub', function ( $query ) {
            $query->where('name', 'Arsenal' );
        })
        ->orWhereHas('awayClub', function ( $query ) {
            $query->where('name', 'Arsenal' );
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. That syntax doesn't seem to work. It doesn't seem that `whereHas` can be used in a subquery. I get the error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'has' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `broadcasts` where (select count(*) from `uploads` where `broadcasts`.`upload_id` = `uploads`.`id` and `type` = international-audience) >= 1 and (select count(*) from `territories` where `broadcasts`.`territory_id` = `territories`.`id` and `region` = Australia) >= 1 and (`has` = homeClub))`

Comment: It seems like the orWhereHas behaves strangely when you enforce other constraints. Refer to my [other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382870/orwherehas-parameter-grouping-on-eloquent-query-how-do-i-do-this-in-laravel) with generated SQL. cheers

Comment: Worked for me! I was doing something similar with a home team and away team related to a games table.  Debugbar told me this is the result:

select * from `games` where `season` = '2' and `series` = '1' and ((select count(*) from `teams` where `teams`.`id` = `games`.`home_team_id` and `user_id` = '1') >= 1 or (select count(*) from `teams` where `teams`.`id` = `games`.`visitor_team_id` and `user_id` = '1') >= 1) order by `series` asc, `home_team_id` asc, `game_number` asc

...I think at this point I'm better off refactoring into a view, though this is a good exercise.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to being shown in the right direction by edi9999 - I wasn't properly considering [parameter grouping](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres)

`use` the main eloquent object in the anonymous function, I placed a whereHas and an orWhereHas constraint on the homeClub and awayClub and that did the trick.

```
$ret->with('territory')->with('homeClub')->with('awayClub')->with('programme');

    $ret
        ->whereHas('territory',function( $query ) use ( $parameterValues ){
            $query->where('region', $parameterValues['region_names'] );
        })
        ->whereHas('season', function ( $query ) use ( $parameterValues ){
            $query->where('name', $parameterValues['season_names'] );
        })
        ->where( function( $subquery ) use ( $ret ){
            $ret->whereHas('homeClub', function ( $query ){
                $query->where('name','Arsenal' );
            } );
            $ret->orWhereHas('awayClub', function ( $query ){
                $query->where('name','Arsenal');
             });
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need 'with' as there is 'wherehas'

```
Model::whereHas('territory',function( $query ){
        $query->where('region','Australia');
    })->whereHas('homeClub', function ( $query ) {
        $query->where('name', 'Arsenal' );
    })->orWhereHas('awayClub', function ( $query ) {
        $query->where('name', 'Arsenal' );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $homeAndLiving    =   Product::with('user')->whereHas('category',function($query){
                          $query->where('category_slug', 'home--living')
                            ->where('is_active','=','on');
                       })
                            ->whereHas('user',function($q){
                          $q->where('is_enabled',1);
                      })->inRandomOrder()->take(6)
                      ->get();
```

This is what works great for me.