# orWhereHas - parameter grouping on Eloquent query - how do I do this in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-4

In an eloquent query I am building, I am placing a constraint on a `has` relationship using Laravel 4.1's `whereHas` and `orWhereHas` methods.

In the example soccer application, I wish to place a constraint on the `homeClub` and `awayClub` relationships so that I can the result set will select where the homeClub = Arsenal OR awayClub = Arsenal.

This issue has evolved from an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335832/laravel-wherehas-on-multiple-relationships) It seems that when using the `orWhereHas` method - the resulting sql doesn't group the `or` constraint.

The query (relevant excerpt that is placing the constraints):

```
$ret
        ->where( function( $subquery ) use ( $ret ){
            $ret->whereHas('homeClub', function ( $query ){
                $query->where('name','Arsenal' );
            })->orWhereHas('awayClub',function ( $query ){
                $query->where('name','Arsenal' );
            });
        })
        ->where( function ( $subquery ) use ( $ret, $parameterValues ){
            $ret->whereHas('season', function ($query) use ( $parameterValues ){
                $query->where('name', $parameterValues['season_names'] );

            });
        } )
        ->whereHas('territory',function( $query ) use ( $parameterValues ){     
               $query->where('region','Australia');

        })->get()->toArray();
```

This produces the sql:

```
SELECT * FROM `broadcasts` WHERE 

(SELECT count(*) FROM `uploads` WHERE `broadcasts`.`upload_id` = `uploads`.`id` and `type` = 'international-audience') >= '1' 
and 
(SELECT count(*) FROM `clubs` WHERE `clubs`.`id` = `broadcasts`.`home_club_id` and `name` = 'Arsenal') >= '1' 
or 
(SELECT count(*) FROM `clubs` WHERE `clubs`.`id` = `broadcasts`.`away_club_id` and `name` = 'Arsenal') >= '1' 
and 
(SELECT count(*) FROM `seasons` WHERE `broadcasts`.`season_id` = `seasons`.`id` and `name` = '2012/13') >= '1' 
and 
(SELECT count(*) FROM `territories` WHERE `broadcasts`.`territory_id` = `territories`.`id` and `region` = 'Australia') >= '1'
```

But, this isn't what I want, because referring to the eloquent statement, the club queries are  [grouped](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres) and the query above either selects the homeClub constraints OR, the awayClub, season name, territory region. What I'm intending is the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `broadcasts` WHERE 

(SELECT count(*) FROM `uploads` WHERE `broadcasts`.`upload_id` = `uploads`.`id` and `type` = 'international-audience') >= '1' 
and 
((SELECT count(*) FROM `clubs` WHERE `clubs`.`id` = `broadcasts`.`home_club_id` and `name` = 'Arsenal') >= '1' 
or 
(SELECT count(*) FROM `clubs` WHERE `clubs`.`id` = `broadcasts`.`away_club_id` and `name` = 'Arsenal') >= '1' )
and 
(SELECT count(*) FROM `seasons` WHERE `broadcasts`.`season_id` = `seasons`.`id` and `name` = '2012/13') >= '1' 
and 
(SELECT count(*) FROM `territories` WHERE `broadcasts`.`territory_id` = `territories`.`id` and `region` = 'Australia') >= '1'
```

Note.. the parentheses on the club subquery.

Does anyone know how I would write this as the eloquent query? I really don't want to have to revert to fluent / joins.

Answer (score 20):

You need to reference the query passed through to the where closure. Otherwise you are adding the grouped where clauses to the main query bypassing any groupings:

```
$ret
->where( function( $query ){
    $query->whereHas('homeClub', function ( $subquery ){
        $subquery->where('name','Arsenal' );
    })
    ->orWhereHas('awayClub',function ( $subquery ){
        $subquery->where('name','Arsenal' );
    });
})
->where( function ( $query ) use ( $parameterValues ){
    $query->whereHas('season', function ($subquery) use ( $parameterValues ){
        $subquery->where('name', $parameterValues['season_names'] );
    });
})
->whereHas('territory',function( $query ) use ( $parameterValues ){     
    $query->where('region','Australia');
})
->get();
```