# How I can ignore current row id one time only

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have custom query where ignored current row id:

```
$relatedVacancies = \App\Vacancy::whereHas('skills', function ($q) use ($vacancy) {
    return $q->whereIn('skill_id', $vacancy->skills->pluck('skill_id')); 
  })->where('id', '!=', $vacancy->id)
  ->orWhere('employment', $vacancy->employment)->where('id', '!=', $vacancy->id)
  ->orWhere('title', 'like', '%'.$vacancy->title.'%')->where('id', '!=', $vacancy->id)
->get();
```

How I can use this condition one time only:

```
->where('id', '!=', $vacancy->id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select based on three conditions:

```
->where([
  ('id', '!=', $vacancy->id),
  ('employment', '=', $vacancy->employment),
  ('title', 'like', '%'.$vacancy->title.'%'),
])->get();
```

Comment: I also included the second parameter of equals in the second conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (based on https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#parameter-grouping):

```
$relatedVacancies = \App\Vacancy::where('id', '!=', $vacancy->id)
         ->whereHas('skills', function ($q) use ($vacancy) {
             return $q->whereIn('skill_id', $vacancy->skills->pluck('skill_id')); 
         })
         ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('employment', $vacancy->employment)
                  ->orWhere('title', 'like', '%'.$vacancy->title.'%');
        })
        ->get();
```

Also check for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23009807/5458355