# Eloquent Get Collection if it has at least one relation

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a scenario where I have a model A that has 3 relations B, C, and D.
I'm trying to get collections in A where it has at least one relation
so I don't want {id:1,B:[],C;[],D:[]} But I would accept {id:2,B:[{id:6}],C;[],D:[]}
I tried getting them by 3 has but that only gets it if it has all 3.
I also tried getting all then checking by if but I want a faster way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel whereHas on multiple relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335832/laravel-wherehas-on-multiple-relationships)

Comment: I checked that question before posting it was vague rather this answer is simpler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `orWhereHas` for that

```
$collectionA = A::where(function($query) {
        $query->whereHas('B')
            ->orWhereHas('C')
            ->orWhereHas('D');
    })
    ->get();
```