# Laravel where, orWhereHas and whereNotIn

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Hello great people of SO!

I hope you all have a good day and have a good health

**Note: I'm not good at SQL**

> Sorry for bad english, but I will try my best to explain my issue

I'm using Laravel v8.x for my app, and after setting up model relationships, events, queues, etc, now I'm working for SQL

ATM, I have 2 Models,

- `User`
- `Post`

Relationships:

- `User` hasMany `Post`
- `User` belongsToMany `User` (Block)
- `User` belongsToMany `User` (Follow)
- `Post` belongsTo `User`

Database:
5 record for `User`
2 record for `Block`
3 records for `Post`

Table: **(Using faker)**

`users`

```
[
    { id: 1, name: 'Jonathan Beatrice', username: 'kiana.fay', ... },
    { id: 2, name: 'Lacey Kirlin', username: 'kenna.turner', ... },
    { id: 3, name: 'Alexander Schiller', username: 'cassandra95', ... },
    { id: 4, name: 'Daniel Wickozky', username: 'nkoepp', ... },
    { id: 5, name: 'Maymie Lehner', username: 'frami.felton', ... }
]
```

`block`

```
[
    { id: 1, by_id: 1, to_id: 2 }, // User #1 block user #2
    { id: 2, by_id: 4, to_id: 1 } // User #4 block user #1
]
```

`posts`

```
[
    { id: 1, user_id: 2, body: 'Test post', ... },
    { id: 2, user_id: 5, body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...', ... },
    { id: 3, user_id: 4, body: 'ABCD festival soon! ...', ... },
]
```

Everything works fine and smooth

Now that I want to implement search system, I have a problem, since **I'm not good with SQL**

Here's my code

`SearchController.php`

```
use ...;
use ...;
...

public function posts(Request $request)
{
    // For testing purpose
    $user = User::with(['userBlocks', 'blocksUser'])->find(1);

    // Get all id of user that $user block
    // return [2]
    $user_blocks = $user->userBlocks->pluck('pivot')->pluck('to_id')->toArray();

    // Get all id of user that block $user
    // return [4]
    $blocks_user = $user->blocksUser->pluck('pivot')->pluck('by_id')->toArray();

    // Merge all ids above (must be unique())
    // return [2, 4]
    $blocks = array_merge($user_blocks, $blocks_user);

    // .../search?q=xxx
    $query = $request->query('q');

    $sql = Post::query();

    // Search for posts that has `posts`.`body` LIKE ? ($query)
    $sql->where('body', 'LIKE', "%$query%");

    // This is where I got confused
    $sql->orWhereHas('user', function ($post_user) use ($blocks, $query) {
        $post_user
            ->whereNotIn('id', $blocks) // Exclude posts that has user and their id not in (x, x, x, x, ... ; $block variable above)
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%") // Find user that has name LIKE ? ($query)
            ->orWhere('username', 'LIKE', "%$query%"); // or Find user that has username LIKE ? ($query)
    });

    $sql->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    $sql->with(['user']);

    $posts = $sql->simplePaginate(10, ['*'], 'p');

    return $posts;
}
```

I run the code, `.../search?q=e`

**Note:**

- All `users` has alphabet `E` in their names
- And also all `posts` has alphabet `E` in their body
- We (as User #1), block User #2, and User #4, block us (User #1)

> Result:  **Controller returned all posts**

This is the query when I use `DB::enableQueryLog()` and `DB::getQueryLog()`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `posts`
WHERE `body` LIKE ?
  AND EXISTS
  (SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `users`
  WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
    AND (
      `id` NOT IN (?)
      AND `username` LIKE ?
      OR `name` LIKE ?
    ))
ORDER BY `created_at` ASC
LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0
```

> Goal: Search all posts that has body LIKE ?, OR posts that has user; username LIKE ? or name LIKE ? (But also exclude the user we block and the user that block us

Thanks in advance

If there's any unclear explanation, I will edit it A.S.A.P

Comment: You may be able to use `whereDoesntHave` ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)) but it's probably going to be tricky seeing how it's a self join

Comment: If I try to understand `whereDoesntHave` method, it will fetch all posts that doesn't have user? Meanwhile, post has to be `belongsTo` a user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I run on my recent laravel install, with my proposed change for one of your issues, version 7.19.1, I get this query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `posts`
WHERE `body` LIKE ?
  OR EXISTS <- line of interest
  (SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `users`
  WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
    AND (
      `id` NOT IN (?)
      AND (`username` LIKE ?
      OR `name` LIKE ?) <- extra brackets ive added
    ))
ORDER BY `created_at` ASC
LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0
```

Have a look at the line of interest, and compare it with the query your version of laravel is running. The `AND EXISTS` line is being incorrectly generated by laravel. `OrWhereHas` isnt behaving correctly in your version, I can't find the release number to see where it was fixed.

Id recommend upgrading to latest if possible, but thats not always an option. I've had a dig around, and it looks like the user in this question here encountered a similar problem:

[WhereHas() / orWhereHas not constraining the query as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116742/wherehas-orwherehas-not-constraining-the-query-as-expected)

You can try moving your `$sql->with(['user']);` to before you OrWhereHas clause. I'm not sure if that will change it to OR, but its worth a try.
Second thing, I've added `whereNested` to your OR clause to ensure the precedence is correct, which adds the extra brackets in the query above, as in you dont want:

```
(`id` NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
      AND `name` LIKE % test %)
      OR `username` LIKE % test %
```

Since then it would include your blocked posts in the exists clause.

So final changes look like this, which I think fufills your description:

```
$sql->with(['user']); //deleted from original position and move here
$sql->where('body', 'LIKE', "%$query%")->whereNotIn('id', $blocks); //additional line 
$sql->orWhereHas('ambience', function ($post_user) use ($blocks, $query) {
    $post_user
        ->whereNotIn('id', $blocks); 
            $post_user->whereNested(function($post_user) use ($query) { //new bit
                $post_user->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%") 
                ->orWhere('username', 'LIKE', "%$query%"); 
            });
});
```

Comment: Is there such method `whereNested()` exist? Idk until u mention it, I'm gonna try ur answer, but rn I'm outside my city

Comment: Ive done a quick search, whereNested has been in laravel since 2015. Ive also ran the above code to get the query above.

Comment: I copied your code above, and it's still showing all posts from everyone (includes people user block, and block user), I'm using Laravel `8.40.0`

Comment: this is the code in my controller rn; `$sql = Post::query();
        $sql->with(['user']);
        $sql->where('body', 'LIKE', "%$query%");
        $sql->orWhereHas('user', function ($post_user) use ($blocks, $query) {
            $post_user->whereNotIn('id', $blocks);
            $post_user->whereNested( function ($post_user) use ($query) {
                $post_user->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                    ->orWhere('username', 'LIKE', "%$query%"); 
            });
        });`

Comment: I've added an additional clause, I think that might be it. Its the `whereNotIn` on the `body LIKE` clause, edited in my answer. Be sure to check the `AND EXISTS` is gone from your `toSql();`.

Comment: `AND EXISTS` gone from my query, thanks to you, I tried switching `orWhereHas()` with `whereHas()`, using `orWhereHas()` return all posts, using `whereHas()` return 0 posts, only array square bracket `[]`, I'm really really confused @_@

Comment: It seems the reason why i got 0 posts, because only 3 posts in my db, i'm sorry, my bad, i'm gonna seed at least 100 record now, I will tell you later if I still got the same issue

Comment: Hi @paul, I see big differences in my query when trying to compare between chaining; `where` and  `orWhere`  with `where` and `whereNested`, and your answer were right, where can I see all Laravel `where` clause?

Comment: theres a list of where's on the manual page: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses , i check regular with toSql() to ensure my where's and brackets are correct. If my where requirements are more complex than whats on offer there, I will drop back to laravels `raw` methods and write raw sql, but I will favour the actual methods on offer before taking that step.